# Erro ao tentar dar npm start em projeto react-native

Tags: react-native

Estou começando no desenvolvimento de apps com react-native, pra aprender criei uma máquina virtual rodando lubuntu e segui o passo a passo de instalação dos pré requisitos:

```
sudo apt-get update

# Instalação do node
sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev
sudo curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh
sudo bash install_nvm.sh
source ~/.profile
sudo nvm ls-remote
sudo nvm install 6.11.2

# Instalação Watchman
sudo apt install git
sudo git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
cd watchman/
sudo git checkout v4.7.0
sudo apt install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo apt install npm

# Instalação Flow
sudo npm install -g flow-bin

# Instalação React-native
sudo npm install -g create-react-native-app

# Criar app
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
```

Mas após acessa a pasta do AwesomeProject e dar o `npm start` a tela trava e fica só em `17:37:54: Starting packager...` e não avança.

Dei um Ctrl+C para encerrar e ao tentar novamente surgiu esse erro:

```
jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
  Error: Watchman error: A non-recoverable condition has triggered.  Watchman needs your help!
The triggering condition was at timestamp=1503002873: inotify-add-watch(/opt/react-apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/lib/build/generated/source/r/release/com/facebook/drawee/backends) -> The user limit on the total number of inotify watches was reached; increase the fs.inotify.max_user_watches sysctl
All requests will continue to fail with this message until you resolve
the underlying problem.  You will find more information on fixing this at
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.
```

Tentei realizar os procedimentos descritos em `https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch` mas nada adiantou

Comment: Já tentou executar o comando 'touch .watchmanconfig' pelo terminal no root do seu projeto?

Comment: Vou tentar, mas agora só segunda

Answer (score -1):

O `npm start` nesse caso apenas irá apenas iniciar o **packager** do React Native. 
Para **instalar** seu aplicativo você tem que ir até a pasta do seu projeto no terminal e executar `npm run android`. Esse comando irá automaticamente encontrar um emulador (caso você tenha algum ativo) ou um device Android plugado na sua máquina e instalar seu aplicativo.

Uma vez que seu app estiver instalado e você abrir ele, o RN vai procurar na sua rede local uma instancia do **Packager** rodando. O packager é quem vai fornecer o código **JavaScript** que você está trabalhando pra seu aplicativo funcionar.

Quanto ao problema do **Watchman**, tente criar um arquivo chamado `.watchmanconfig` na pasta do seu projeto e apenas digite `{}` dentro do mesmo.

Comment: Vou tentar esse do Watchman, porém quanto ao `npm start` ele por si só é para gerar um QR code que vc pode ler com o aplicativo expo (https://expo.io) e assim emular no próprio celular sem necessitar estar plugado ao pc, como está descrito aqui https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score -1):

Basicamente o que eu fiz foi desinstalar o watchman. Como você instalou por make, imagino que, dentro da pasta do watchman, o comando abaixo funcione:

```
$ sudo make uninstall
```

Outra diferença é que não usei o `npm`, mas sim o `yarn`. Então com `yarn start` eu obtive a seguinte mensagem:

```
yarn start
yarn run v1.1.0
$ react-native-scripts start
11:15:08 AM: Unable to start server
  See https://git.io/v5vcn for more information, either install watchman or run the following snippet:
    sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
    sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=12288
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Logo, simplesmente fiz o que me foi recomendado:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=12288
```

Depois disso, executei novamente `yarn start`, recebi meu QR-Code e abri o App pelo [expo.io](https://expo.io/) que funcionou perfeitamente.

---

Obs.:

1. Post prático sobre [yarn](https://tableless.com.br/yarn-evolucao-do-npm/);
2. Rodar o App sem watchman não é muito recomendável, por isso sugiro
   que caso funcione sem ele, tente mais tarde entender e resolver
   essas questões.